# how to create multiple username and password in case of tortoise svn

Tags: svn

i am using tortoise svn and i want to create 20 credentials(i.e username and password) so that every individual can log into their respective id and checkout the code from svn repository.so that it can be easy to find out who is that person who commit the particular code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform any **server-side task** with **client**. Ask you SVN-admin to do it